# Why is the Dragboard image content blurry and cropped?

Tags: java, image, drag-and-drop, javafx-8

I'm trying to implement a simple drag and drop feature in a GridPane and I want to put an Image as visual representation of the current dragged object.

It works good so far but as soon as the image exceeds a certain size it gets blurry and cropped. You can find my current implementation below:

```
pane.setOnDragDetected(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
            public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
                Dragboard db = pane.startDragAndDrop(TransferMode.ANY);

                SnapshotParameters snapParams = new SnapshotParameters();
                snapParams.setFill(Color.TRANSPARENT);
                Image dragImage = pane.snapshot(snapParams, null);


                ClipboardContent content = new ClipboardContent();
                content.putImage(dragImage);
                db.setContent(content);

                event.consume();
            }
        });
```

As long as I'm dragging one of the small objects the preview dragging image looks like as it is shown below.
[image]

But for the big object the preview image looks like this.
[image]

It seems when the image is larger than a certain size this visual effect will be added. Is there a chance to render the image in its real size? Maybe I missed something in the documentation, if yes please let me know.

Comment: Does `db.setDragView(dragImage)` work? (And why do you have the second, seemingly redundant, call to `snapshot()`?)

Comment: No it isn't working, I've also tried this before but the effect is the same. In regarding to the second redundant call I've updated the answer, it was just a mistake in my simplified example code.